# Emulating a Windows shortcut in Python

Tags: python, windows

This is probably a fairly simple question, but I have gone thoroughly overwhelmed trying to figure it out.

I want to start another program in Windows from Python 2.6. I have the "command-line argument" figured out so that if I create shortcut and double-click on it the other program opens, does what it needs to, and then closes.

I started with the subprocess library, but that seemed not to work. I got overwhelmed looking at all of the different versions of  "popen"

How do I run in an external program from Python like I had double-clicked on a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below maybe?

```
import os
os.system("notepad")
```

Or:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["notepad"])
```

The below question has some excellent answers:

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It seems to be something wrong with the argument I'm calling on my external program… Although it works fine as a shortcut, and returns immediately without doing anything as a argument to os.system. Shrug, Well Thanks for the help.